# Fill a list with N characters at the end of it Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to fill a list with N characters at the end of it in Prolog.
Without libraries or maplist,findall commands.

I tried this code which was creating recursively more lists with "e" characters at the end but I needed one list.

```
append_e(_,0,[]). 
append_e(List,E_size_loop,[ListTemp|List0]):- 
   E_size_loop>0, 
   N2 is E_size_loop-1, 
   append(List,[e],ListTemp), 
   append_e(ListTemp,N2,List0).
```

and this one was erasing my previous list and replacing it with my desired number of e characters

```
append_e(_,0,[]).
append_e(List,E_size_loop,ListTemp):-
   E_size_loop>0,
   N2 is E_size_loop-1,
   append_e(List,N2,ListO),
   append(ListO,[e],ListTemp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
append_e(Xs, N, Ys) :-
   length(Es, N),
   maplist(=(e), Es),
   append(Xs, Es, Ys).
```

length and maplist can be combined into one definition:

```
append_e(Xs, N, Ys) :-
   n_es(N, Es),
   append(Xs, Es, Ys).

n_es(N, Es) :-
   length(Es, N),
   maplist(=(e), Es).
```

which in turn might be defined manually for the case that N is instantiated

```
n_es(N0, [e|Es]) :-
   N0 > 0,
   N1 is N0-1,
   n_es(N1, Es).
n_es(0, []).
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to create it without maplist... I wrote it in description.

Comment: In the meantime you should be able to translate above maplist goal into a corresponding maplist-free version

Comment: It works very good but I need to do it recursively and I fail !

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the input list until you reach its end and then add the `N` copies of the given character:

```
fill_list([], Character, N, List) :-
    fill_with_character(Character, N, List).
fill_list([Head| Tail0], Character, N, [Head| Tail]) :-
    fill_list(Tail0, Character, N, Tail).
```

The `fill_with_character/3` predicate can simply do a countdown while copying the character:

```
fill_with_character(_, 0, []) :- !.
fill_with_character(Character, N, [Character| Tail]) :-
    N > 0,
    M is N - 1,
    fill_with_character(Character, M, Tail).
```

The cut in the first clause is a green cut that avoids a spurious choice point.

Sample call:

```
| ?- fill_list([a,b,c], d, 2, L).

L = [a,b,c,d,d]
yes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but It doesn't seem to work an error appears  Syntax error: Operator priority clash in second sentence and if I remove the cut it dissapears but another error appears in running mode

Comment: Copy and paste the code above into a Prolog session shows no syntax error.

Comment: Something was conflicting with the other code I had its ok thank you again !